# need help in asp.net folder browsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

there is a folderbrowserdialog control in winform but not in asp.net
is there anyway to get the control working in asp.net??
if no, how can i implement a control similar to folderbrowserdialog in asp?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: i need a control like folderbrowserdialog for asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Browsers don't have the ability to select folder, and certainly not to upload them as a whole.